# Power Regulation from Arduino Micro

Tags: arduino, power-supply, capacitor

I am using the Arduino Micro as the microcontroller for an optical detection circuit that consists of a photodiode, trans impedance op amp, and ADC.

Using the +5V power pin from the Arduino Micro to power my entire system, must I regulate this power source using DC/DC converters and decoupling capacitors to provide stable power over time?

[image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic of what you have and how it’s connected. Click on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: You are missing a feedback resistor between the amplifier output and inverting input. It will probably also need a compensation capacitor in parallel with the capacitor.

Comment: Yes I forgot to include those in the schematic, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the USB-connection to supply power to your circuit: you are good to go Sir! You may have a ripple on your supply which can cause problems with ADC-accuracy - but if you are good with 8Bit precision no problems here.

If you use the VIN-Port you have to do nothing. The internal LDO will provide the +5V rail.

Depending on the required bandwidth of the signal you intend to measure: If you are okay with a low bandwidth you could 'low-pass' filter your ADC signal to get rid of the ripple. Also, you could provide a highly stable external VREF to your ADC.

As general advice: a 100n,1u and 4u7 cap on the +5v will do no harm.

**Edit:**

My suggestions. Probably overkill. Make sure you design all these low passes within your desired signal specifications in mind. This also implements an external reference which makes your life easier here. You can use a zener type implementation or a ready-to-go IC. In Block [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9k2u.jpg) make sure to use highly stable resistors (Not highly precise but highly stable -> low drift). Also make sure to designe the divider in such a way, that your full scale range is not violated due to the use of a low voltage external reference voltage. Also make sure, that BLock [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9k2u.jpg) does ot have a high impedance (5% of ADC Input impedance) in your desired frequency band (I Assume DC).

[image]

**Edit-Edit:**

As you asked for further help I did a little thinking. I changed your circuit to fit the needs I know of. First of all I removed the external ADC. The controller does have an internal 10 Bit device which can be oversampled to 11 or even 12 bit resolution. This simplifies the layout quite a lot. Also, I attached all component values. I therefore assumed that you want to measure only 'Low frequency' changes in the 10Hz region. If you want to measure 'faster' changes please change the RC filter near block [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e91U7.jpg).

**Note:**

I drew this in about 15minutes and did no comprehensive error or detail checking.

[image: The Circuit i suggest]

[image: Note to block 1]

[image: Notes to block 2 and 3]

[image: Note to block 4]

Comment: sorry, but how exactly can I find the values for the resistors and capacitors for the low pass filters and decoupling capacitors?